# Would it be possible to create a vehicle completely from organic material?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

I've wanted to make a planet where everyday lifestyle is exactly like here on  Earth, but everything is organic material. Of course,vehicles like cars would be extremely ambitious. But, could we manipulate an animal's brain to make it move, without liability of losing control?(Nightmare fuel warning) Or should we disassemble an animal's carcass and reassemble it into said vehicle? {EDIT} Specifically, Make a functional "Vehicle" (Operator has complete control, and the "vehicle" has no free will or consciousness) from completely organic material (Material of which a living creature or plant was once composed of, and not rotted to the point where it is practically soil), and still functional. Any animal or plant may be used. Type of vehicle doesn't matter, whether it's planes, trains, automobiles, or other.{EDIT2} It cant be considered a living thing, so you dont have to worry about the circulatory, respiratory, etc. Example: a pod on legs. can this be made?

Comment: Like.... a horse?

Comment: No, a full-blown vehicle. Not living. no feed

Comment: What are you asking? Could a rotting carcass be made to move a bit? Ever placed electrodes in a dead frog's spine? - if the cells have metabolism, is that not living? VTC - not clear what you are asking. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: All engines require fuel, whether it's oats for a horse, caffeine for a human, or gasoline.  Given the right kinds of wood, I could probably make a working car out of wood (so long as you don't expect to move very fast).  What are you trying to ask?  What are the requirements of an "organic" vehicle?  Exactly what *kind* of vehicle are we talking about?

Comment: "Organic" does not mean "of biological origin". For example, the tyres of my car are made of organic material, but they don't come from animals or plants. Rubber is organic. Plastic is organic. Plexiglas is organic.

Comment: @John Dvorak I do not know why, but I read your comment and just started laughing.

Comment: @AlexP raises an incredibly good point.  There are many definitions to [organic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/organic).  Two are, (a) of, relating to, or derived from living organisms and (b) of, relating to, or containing carbon compounds.  It gets worse if you keep reading the definitions.  What, exactly, do you mean by "organic."

Comment: "Organic substance" always means "a substance with a chemical formula derived from a hydrocarbon", and never "a substance made by an organism". "Organic glass" always means "a glassy organic substance" and never "glass derived from an animal product". On the other hand, "organic coating" means "a coating with an organic substance" for an engineer, but "the coating of an organ" for a biologist. And "organic food" always means "food produced in accordance to some code which enables the producer to charge more", and never "food made of organic substances" (because *all* food is).

Comment: @GreenieE. Thanks for the edit for clarity. I'll delete my post now, so not to clutter your answers :)

Comment: @AlexP: Well, if you want to get picky, most of those are of biological origin.  Natural rubber of course does come from a plant:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hevea_brasiliensis  The rest are (AFAIK) derived from petrochemicals, the source of which is ultimately biological.  If your world lacks plentiful petroleum deposits, you could probably synthesize them directly from plants.

Comment: You might take a look at Harry Harrison's *Eden* trilogy, where evolved dinosaurs use technology entirely based on animals carefully bred over millennia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_of_Eden

Answer (score 4):

Early bicycles had wooden wheels and a wooden frame.  Red River carts had wooden wheels and axles.

So, yes, a muscle powered vehicle is quite possible.

The bearings at the Slave Falls power dam, built in 1911 have lignum vitae bearings -- a very hard, naturally greasy wood.  Lubricate with water.

Given that these bearings have a long service live (In 1980 when I toured the dam, they were still using the original set.) I think it would be reasonable to use them for building engines.

You can boil water in a birch bark cup.  The evaporation of the water keeps the cup below the kindling point.

But a pressure boiler would be tough.  I think doing pressure based plumbing would be tough too.

Hmm.  Rubber contracts when heated, expands when cooled.  Anything that changes dimension when undergoing a temperature change is a potential engine.  Whether it would make an efficient engine is more problematic.

Are you using organic to mean "compounds that have carbon" or are you using organic like the food nutters do, "Containing no artificial poisons, only natural ones"

The latter would allow ceramics, and minerals.

See the SF story, "That Share of Glory" by C. M. Kornbluth for a story that takes place on a metal lacking world. Ceramic turbine engines fueled with powdered coal.

Answer (score 3):

Training an animal to carry you around is called "riding" and an animal trained to carry stuff for you is called a "pack animal". Humanity is very successful at training animals that way for millennia, long before the discovery of neurosurgery.

If you are thinking of an animal with wheels, well, [that's more complicated than you think](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAGEOKAG0zw). A wheeled vehicle can only work when there is no permanent connection between the axle and the body of the vehicle. But with biotechnology that's difficult, because you can hardly have a circulatory system that way. The body of the vehicle and the wheels would need to be independent creatures. And this form of co-dependent evolution is very unlikely.

Comment: But codependent genetic engineering, maybe.....

Comment: @Sonvar I'm all ears for your design. Even with multiple organisms, you have to figure out lubrication. Also, a way to feed each component creature.

Comment: You could have a circulatory system, just as an automobile engine has an oil circulation system.  You'd just need to evolve the biological equivalent of an oil seal.  And make it self-repairing :-)

Comment: Mucus makes a sufficient lubricant. Being a warped and genetically jacked creature, the tortured beings may need special care of feeding and watering or else you can parts would die.